# make oldconfig doesn't work

Tags: kernel

I have installed ubunu 16.04 on my Dell machine and would like to build the vanilla kernel using the configuration file already in the /boot directory.
I have copied the version indicated by uname -a to the directory containing the kernel  source code and renamed to it to .config but make oldconfig returns no rule to build oldconfig error – is this what is expected and how this can be fixed please?

Comment: Without seeing the command you typed, and the results, we cannot help you.

Comment: Even better, use localmodconfig - `make localmodconfig`  "Since the 2.6.32 kernel, a new feature allows you to update the configuration to only compile modules that are actually used in your system:

`make localmodconfig`"

Comment: Many thanks for your helps!Another question is that when I

Comment: Many thanks for your helps! 
The command I am using and the response is as follows:

>> make oldconfig
>> make: *** No rule to make target 'oldconfig'. Stop.

Another question is that when I issue 'uname -a ' command to find out what configuration to copy from /boot and rename to .config, response to the command shows a different configuration used in the current boot-up session from the one I had in the previous session. There are three different config files in /boot directory - does it matter which one to use?
Thanks again  in advance for your helps.

Comment: I just used the 'make localmodconfig' and I am getting the same response:  "make: *** No rule to make target 'localmodconfig'. Stop."

Comment: Someone gave me a config file that worked on his similar machine and I have passed the hurdle. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @waltinator No, oldconfig is supposed to be a pseudotarget in a makefile.  That is how make works. We don't rename things, the dependencies with their original names are in the makefile. But we need the correct makefile.